# Is there somewhere I can work on a laptop in or near London Euston station?

Tags: uk, trains, london, layovers, work

I have a longish layover in London Euston and I have some work to do. Working includes using a laptop, ideally with a power socket, and paper notebooks. Is there somewhere I can work in or near London Euston? I'd be even willing to pay for access in a first class lounge.

Comment: Euston station is hideous. I'd strongly recommend looking for a coffee shop nearby.

Comment: The Virgin lounge has wifi and powerpoints, but you'd need a first class ticket.  However, you might find a cheap one online you could dispose of...hypothetically ;)

Comment: There's an internet cafe on Gray's Inn Road at the corner of St Chad's.  Exit Euston, turn left and follow Euston Road to Gray's Inn Road (huge intersection), turn right on to Gray's Inn.  About 150 m to St Chads, cross St Chad's and you're there.  Walking time 10 mins

Comment: British Library is next door and has all the Wi-Fi, power and coffee you could need.

Comment: This might help http://james.cridland.net/blog/where-to-get-free-wifi-to-do-some-work-in-london/

Comment: I'm kinda cruious what kind of rail journey would leave you at Euston for hours that doesn't have a more direct routing. Also, yes, Euston is awful, competeing with the old Birmingham New Street and Manchester Victoria in "major stations that are unpleasant places to be"

Comment: @CMaster Coming from France, going to Wales.

Comment: Wouldn't somewhere at St Pancras also be acceptable then? - Not that this isn't a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @CMaster Yes. Why not? Note that I ask for in or near Euston Station. Go ahead and post an answer. :)

Comment: @CMaster Probably North Wales Coast Line. Chester is hourly, but there are only four or five trains beyond there in a day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Euston Station itself also has free wifi, but power points are tricky and it is super busy/noisy.  I would highly recommend the [British Library](http://www.bl.uk/) which is just down the road (see the website for a map & opening times).  It has everything you need - free wifi (you will need to sign up), powerpoints, toilets, coffee shops.  There are even a few exhibits if you want to take a break and stretch your legs.

Just go in, find a seat on one of the many floors, turn on your wifi and log in to the library (BL visitor from what I remember) and follow the instructions. There is a little more info on the website, or when you arrive there is a huge information desk (you really can't miss it).

Comment: Is it free access? Do I need to register? Do I need a library card to access the facilities/services? Be pedagogical: teach the man to fish. :)

Comment: Yes its free access.  Just go in, find a seat on one of the many floors, turn on your wifi and log in to the library (BL visitor from what I remember) and follow the instructions.  There is a little more info on the website (link in my answer), or when you arrive there is a huge information desk (you really can't miss it).

Comment: @HoboSci - Please edit that stuff in to your answer, especially the part about free access (some guidance on opening times might also be useful)

Comment: It's not next door, but only about 500m away. Are you thinking of Kings Cross/St Pancras?

Comment: @CMaster - done

Comment: @e100 - sorry - figure of speech (which made more sense to me at 4am).  I have edited the OP to make it more clear

Comment: @e100 I *was* thinking of KC/StP.

Comment: @JoErNanO The BL also has a [Business and IP Centre](http://www.bl.uk/bipc/) which gives you access to all kinds of databases etc. You need to [register as a Reader to get access](http://www.bl.uk/reshelp/inrrooms/stp/register/howreg/howtoregister.html), which you can do on the spot if you bring your passport and a utility bill. While you're there, don't miss the Gutenburg Bible and the Diamond Sutra (earliest printed book). Also: [opening hours](http://www.bl.uk/aboutus/quickinfo/loc/stp/opening/?ns_campaign=brand&ns_mchannel=ppc&ns_source=google&ns_linkname=Bl%20opening%20times&ns_fee=0).

Comment: @HoboSci Don't be afraid to add the information provided by AE in your answer.

Comment: Note that the BL does not like you coming in with substantial luggage, so if you have a large suitcase this may not work.

Comment: @Andrew But don't forget there is left luggage at Euston, so you could leave your case there.